# Common Url for server and client in Blazor

Tags: c#, routes, blazor

Hello i do not understand the following:

What i want to achieve:

I have a `ASP NET Core` standalone project that responds with some json to the followig routes :
`localhost:8300/a`
`localhost:8300/b`

Now i am adding to the solution a simple `Blazor` project template (not server-sided ,nor client-hosted ) ,just the client project.

How do i set the `Url` for the `client` and the `server` so that i can still respond with json on the mentioned routes , (example from `Postman`) but i can acess the `Blazor` client on some chosen route:
 `[address]:[port]/c` 
I do not understand the address and the port part.

Comment: Are you using client-side or server-side Blazor?

Comment: I am using client-side blazor.

Comment: Have you used the standard Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted) template or have you created a stand alone Blazor app and then added a MVC application?

Comment: I have tried both methods ,but currently i have them separate.First created a `Blazor app` from the simple template, and the server is a different web api.In this mode , i set the url of the `Client` to `localhost:8300` and the server `localhost:8500` and i can acess the website on both.However now all my web-api server routes like `localhost:8500/route` stopped working.

Comment: If you create an app using the Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted) template then you will get a single URL for your application. But I'm not 100% sure what you're looking to achieve past that?

Comment: I want to know if a have two different projects : a `server` that already has some `REST` `routes` that responds and a `Blazor` template.If i want to keep the server routes working but i want on top of that to acess the `client` from the browser on a route..how should the `URI`-s be set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187240/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-chris-sainty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main idea with .NET Code integration for these sorts of problems is create separate WebApplication which will just add references to you `API` and `BlazorClient` client projects. Lets call that new App `CombinedApp` for clearer reference.

if you duplicate initialization of `API` inside `CombinedApp`. Inside `Startup` class you should perform same initialization inside `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods. That bring routes from `API` project to the `CombinedApp` project. Then add `UseBlazor<BlazorClient.Program>()` in the `Configure` method of `CombinedApp.Startup` and then you have both API and BlazorClient sitting in the same project.